# How to pass an id of current item to request table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have an application where a user can send request edit to the admin, now the problem is how to store the id of the requested asset from user_asset table to the request table so I can display it to the admin's page with full details of the asset

when the user clicks on the request edit he gets a form with editable fields filled with current information but how can I store this asset's *id* so I can fetch it to the admin's table with information from both tables *(user_assets, requests)*

I have *user_asset table*

```
asset_id
asset_category
code
title
userid
```

and requests table

```
id
reason
assetid
user_id
```

this is what I have done so far

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    // get all values from input with no special charactere

   $code = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['code']);

   $asset_id =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']); 
   $reason =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['reason']);

    if (!$error) {


      if (!$error) {
         // execute the sql insert 
            if(mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `requests`(id,reason,assetid, user_id) 
                 VALUES( null, '" . $reason . "', '". $asset_id ."','" .$_SESSION['user_id'] . "')")) {
              // if the insert result was true (OK)
              $success_message = "req was successfully added ! ";
           } else {
              // if the insert result was false (KO)
              $error_message = "Error in data...Please try again later!";
           }
        }
   }


}

else{
   if(isset($_GET['idedit']) ){
       $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from user_asset WHERE asset_id=".$_GET['idedit']);
       $project = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
   }

}

   ?>
```

and this is my form

```
            <form method="post" action="req_ade.php" id="adding_new_assets">


                                    <div class="control-group">
                                       <label  for="basicinput">الکود : </label>
                                       <div class="controls">
                                          <input type="number" id="basicinput" value="<?php echo $project['code']; ?>" placeholder="الكود" name="code" class="span8">
                                       </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="control-group">
                                       <label  for="basicinput">التفاصيل : </label>
                                       <div class="controls">
                                          <input type="text" id="basicinput" value="<?php echo $project['title']; ?>" placeholder="التفاصيل" name="title" class="span8">
                                       </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div>
                             <label style="color:black">السبب</label>
                             <textarea rows="8" cols="8" name="reason" class="form-control" placeholder="اذكر سبب التعديل ..." ></textarea>

                            </div>

                                    <div class="control-group">
                                       <div class="controls">
                                          <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn">طلب تعديل</button>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </form>
```

these are the errors I'm getting

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in D:\wamp64\www\Caprabia-test\req_ade.php on line 28

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'assetid' at row 1' in D:\wamp64\www\Caprabia-test\req_ade.php on line 37

( ! ) mysqli_sql_exception: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'assetid' at row 1 in D:\wamp64\www\Caprabia-test\req_ade.php on line 37
```

Comment: Please remove single quote from SQL as it must be integer in the database and try :  VALUES( null, '" . $reason . "', ". $asset_id .",'" .$_SESSION['user_id'] . "')")

Comment: @suhaspandit - Removing the single quotes will open the query for SQL injections and fix nothing.

Comment: The reason why it fails is because you don't check if the values are set and you don't use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your suggestions.

After trying a lot of suggestions and manipulating with the code I have found a solution for it.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

   // get all values from input with no special charactere

  $code = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['code']);

  $asset_id =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['asset_id']); 
  $reason =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['reason']);

   if (!$error) {


     if (!$error) {
        // execute the sql insert 
           if(mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `requests1`(id,reason,assetid, user_id) 
                VALUES( null, '" . $reason . "', '". $asset_id ."','" .$_SESSION['user_id'] . "')")) {
             // if the insert result was true (OK)
             $success_message = "req was successfully added ! ";
          } else {
             // if the insert result was false (KO)
             $error_message = "Error in data...Please try again later!";
          }
       }
  }


}

else{
   if(isset($_GET['idedit']) ){
       $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from user_asset WHERE asset_id=".$_GET['idedit']);
       $project = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
   }

}
```

and this is the form I have posted the *asset_id* in a hidden type

```
  <form method="post" action="req_ade1.php" id="adding_new_assets">


                                    <div class="control-group">
                                       <label  for="basicinput">الکود : </label>
                                       <div class="controls">
                                       <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $project['asset_id'];?>" name="asset_id" />
                                       <input type="number" id="basicinput" value="<?php echo $project['code']; ?>" placeholder="الكود" name="code" class="span8">
                                       </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="control-group">
                                       <label  for="basicinput">التفاصيل : </label>
                                       <div class="controls">
                                          <input type="text" id="basicinput" value="<?php echo $project['title']; ?>" placeholder="التفاصيل" name="title" class="span8">
                                       </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div>
                             <label style="color:black">السبب</label>
                             <textarea rows="8" cols="8" name="reason" class="form-control" placeholder="اذكر سبب التعديل ..." ></textarea>

                            </div>

                                    <div class="control-group">
                                       <div class="controls">
                                          <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn">طلب تعديل</button>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Notice: Undefined index: id in D:\wamp64\www\Caprabia-test\req_ade.php on line 28**

There is no "id" in your $_GET array. So your $asset_id variable will be empty and a empty string is not a valid int number. You should add (int) in your query:

```
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `requests`(id,reason,assetid, user_id) 
             VALUES( null, '" . $reason . "', '". (int)$asset_id ."','" .$_SESSION['user_id'] . "')")
```

Or better check the the $_GET array before you use it. Like this:

```
If(isset($_GET['id'])) 
{
     $asset_id =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']);
}
else 
{
     ...
}
```